# Writing a compressed buffer to a gzip compatible file

Tags: c++, gzip, zlib

I would like to compress a bunch of data in a buffer and write to a file such that it is gzip compatible. The reason for doing this is that I have multiple threads that can be compressing their own data in parallel and require a lock only when writing to the common output file.

I have some dummy code below based on the `zlib.h` docs for writing a gz compatible, but I get a `gzip: test.gz: unexpected end of file` when I try to decompress the output. Can anyone tell me what might be going wrong ?

Thank you

```
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <zlib.h>


int main()
{

    char compress_in[50] = "I waaaaaaaant tooooooo beeeee compressssssed";
    char compress_out[100];

    z_stream bufstream;
    bufstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    bufstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    bufstream.opaque = Z_NULL;

    bufstream.avail_in = ( uInt )strlen(compress_in) + 1;
    bufstream.next_in = ( Bytef * ) compress_in;
    bufstream.avail_out = ( uInt )sizeof( compress_out );
    bufstream.next_out = ( Bytef * ) compress_out;

    int res = deflateInit2( &bufstream, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED, 15 + 16, 8, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY );
    assert ( res == Z_OK );

    res = deflate( &bufstream, Z_FINISH );
    assert( res == Z_STREAM_END );

    deflateEnd( &bufstream );

    std::ofstream outfile( "test.gz", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out );
    outfile.write( compress_out, strlen( compress_out ) + 1 );
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is C++. Please don't tag other vastly different languages.

Comment: can you be 100% certain that `compress_out` contains no embedded null characters and that `strlen( compress_out )` will return the correct value? I'm not sure that you can.

Comment: You can't use `strlen` on binary data. You need to use the sizes returned by zlib instead

Comment: You have to loop until it is done.

Comment: I can't find a good documentation page for `z_stream` to confirm which of it's members you want to use to determine the amount of output data. `next_out` and `total_out` sound like good candidates, but I'm out of time and cannot confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the compressed data written to the output buffer is the space you provided for the output buffer minus the space remaining in the output buffer. So, `sizeof( compress_out ) - bufstream.avail_out`. Do:

```
outfile.write( compress_out, sizeof( compress_out ) - bufstream.avail_out );
```